# How to align ticks with bars in horizontal bar chart / row chart

Tags: d3.js

I've created a horizontal bar chart / row chart and am struggling to vertically align the Y-axis ticks with the center of my bars.

To create the Y-axis I'm using the following code:

```
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.subject;
  }));
  .rangeRoundBands([0, height]);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
```

And creating my bars like so:

```
  // Render the bars
  svg.selectAll('bar')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', 1)
    .attr('y', function (d) {
      return yScale(d.subject);
    })
    .attr('width', function (d) {
      return xScale(d.value)
    })
    .attr('height', barHeight)
    .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
      return color(i);
    });
```

I'd like to be able to set the height of my chart to any value and have the ticks aligned correctly.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/sp339/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that you assigned an arbitrary `barHeight` value of 40 units.

When you use an ordinal scale with `rangeRoundBands`, d3 calculates a band size for you. You should use this value for your bar height. You can access the value that was calculated for your bands as [`ordinal.rangeBand`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#ordinal_rangeBand), or in your specific case, `yScale.rangeBand`.

```
// instead of `barHeight`
.attr('height', yScale.rangeBand);
```

To avoid having all of your bars touching one another, you can give a second parameter to your `rangeRoundBands` method which is the padding between bands. Play around with the values for padding until you get the desired output.

Here's an updated [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ud2E/)